# How can I add UIImageView as subview of UIImageView on SDK 8 for iOS?

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, ios8, subview

How can I add `UIImageView` as subview of `UIImageView` on SDK 8 for iOS? It has worked on the previous SDK but now the both images are displayed on point (0; 0). The `frame` property is ignored.

Comment: Should I add constraints? Or how can I disable them to use 'frame' property for `UIImageView` coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped:

```
    subviewImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```